# ASP.net Hiding Properties

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I have a class declaration

```
public class Customer
{

  public string id {  get;set;}
  public Address CustomerAddress   { get;set;}
  ...
  ...
  ...
  public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
  ..
  ..
  ..
}
```

during `debugging` i want to hide some properties from being displayed like (id,CustomerAddress),what is the way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
System.Diagnostics.[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
```

(i.e)

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public Address CustomerAddress   { get;set;}
```